# What are WSDL, SOAP and REST?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, wsdl

What is [WSDL](https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl)? How is it related to [SOAP](https://www.w3.org/TR/soap12)? Where does [REST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6690) fit in all of that?

Answer (score 224, accepted):

A WSDL is an XML document that describes a web service.  It actually stands for Web Services Description Language.

SOAP is an XML-based protocol that lets you exchange info over a particular protocol (can be HTTP or SMTP, for example) between applications.  It stands for Simple Object Access Protocol and uses XML for its messaging format to relay the information.

REST is an architectural style of networked systems and stands for Representational State Transfer.  It's not a standard itself, but does use standards such as HTTP, URL, XML, etc.

Comment: I meant to put SMTP or HTTP as examples of protocols that SOAP can be used over.  I didn't intend it to mean HTTP is the only protocol that can be used (was just using it as an example).

Comment: Representational State Transfer (REST) is an architectural style that specifies constraints, such as the uniform interface, that if applied to a web service induce desirable properties, such as performance, scalability, and modifiability, that enable services to work best on the Web. In REST style, data and functionality are considered resources and are accessed using Uniform Resource Identifiers (URIs). The resources are acted upon by using a set of simple, well-defined operations. it follows client/server architecture and is designed to use a stateless communication protocol,typically HTTP.

Comment: Isn't the 'D' in WSDL stand for "Description" instead of "Definition"?

Comment: `"A WSDL is an XML document that describes a web service. It actually stands for Web Services Definition Language."` 
This really doesn't explain what it is...

Comment: @Sparkzz according to wikipedia:
`The current version of WSDL is WSDL 2.0. The meaning of the acronym has changed from version 1.1 where the "D" stood for "Definition".`

Comment: Why is wsdl needed? REST doesnt need it. Developer can see the documentation. Why is advertising the capability along with input and output argument necessary?

Comment: It isn't needed, it does provide the ability for the developer to automatically generate the client classes they need to interact with the service though.

Comment: A WSDL just makes it significantly easier to manage and auto-generate the SOAP client. WSDL's are essentially the contract between two SOAP endpoints. We can keep them in sync by versioning the WSDL and storing WSDL somewhere publicly available (or secured if required).

Comment: @MinhNghĩa REST is not self-describing, by itself. A SOAP web service with a WSDL is. A REST service with something like Swagger is more or less self-describing.

Answer (score 135):

Example: In a simple terms if you have a web service of calculator.

WSDL: WSDL tells about the functions that you can implement or exposed to the client. For example: add, delete, subtract and so on.

SOAP: Where as using SOAP you actually perform actions like doDelete(), doSubtract(), doAdd(). So SOAP and WSDL are apples and oranges. We should not compare them. They both have their own different functionality.

Why we use SOAP and WSDL: For platform independent data exchange.

EDIT: In a normal day to day life example:

**WSDL:** When we go to a restaurant we see the Menu Items, those are the WSDL's.

**Proxy Classes:** Now after seeing the Menu Items we make up our Mind (Process our mind on what to order): So, basically we make Proxy classes based on WSDL Document.

**SOAP:** Then when we actually order the food based on the Menu's: Meaning we use proxy classes to call upon the service methods which is done using SOAP. :)

Answer (score 46):

Every time someone mentions SOAP/WSDL, I think of objects and classes defined in xml...

> *"You use SOAP just the same way that you would any PHP class. However, in this case the class does not exist in the local applications file system, but at a remote site accessed over http."*
> ...
> *"If we think of using a SOAP service as just another PHP class then the WSDL document is a list of all the available class methods and properties. "*
>
> http://www.doublehops.com/2009/07/07/quick-tutorial-on-getting-started-with-soap-in-php/comment-page-1/

..and whenever someone talks about REST I think of HTTP's commands (request methods) like POST, GET and DELETE

Answer (score 24):

SOAP -> SOAP(Simple object access protocol) is the application level protocol created for machine to machine interaction. Protocol defines standard rules. All the parties who are using the particular protocol should adhere to the protocol rules. Like TCP, It unwinds at transport layer, The SOAP protocol will be understood by Application layer( any application which supports SOAP - Axis2, .Net).

WSDL -> SOAP message consist of SoapEnevelope->SoapHeader and SoapBody. It doesn't define what would be message format? what are all the transports(HTTP,JMS) it supports? without this info, It is hard for any client who wants to consume the particular web service to construct the SOAP message. Even if they do, they won't be sure, it'll work all the time. WSDL is the rescue. WSDL (Web Service description Language) defines the operations, message formats and transport details for the SOAP message.

REST -> REST(Representational state transfer) is based on the Transport. Unlike SOAP which targets the actions, REST concerns more on the resources. REST locates the resources by using URL (example -http://{serverAddress}/employees/employeeNumber/12345) and it depends on the transport protocol( with HTTP - GET,POST, PUT, DELETE,...) for the actions to be performed on the resources. The REST service locates the resource based on the URL and perform the action based on the transport action verb. It is more of architectural style and conventions based.

Answer (score 20):

You're not going to "simply" understand something complex.

WSDL is an XML-based language for describing a web service. It describes the messages, operations, and network transport information used by the service. These web services usually use SOAP, but may use other protocols.

A WSDL is readable by a program, and so may be used to generate all, or part of the client code necessary to call the web service. This is what it means to call SOAP-based web services "self-describing".

REST is not related to WSDL at all.

Comment: Uhm, if you can use it for other protocols too, why does no one describe REST-APIs with WDSL?

Answer (score 13):

SOAP stands for Simple (sic) Object Access Protocol.  It was intended to be a way to do Remote Procedure Calls to remote objects by sending XML over HTTP.

WSDL is Web Service Description Language.  A request ending in '.wsdl' to an endpoint will result in an XML message describing request and response that a use can expect.  It descibes the contract between service & client.

REST uses HTTP to send messages to services.

SOAP is a spec, REST is a style.

Comment: -1: sorry, but I disagree with associating SOAP with RPC. What about message-style services? Also, there's no standard that says a request ending in .wsdl or ?wsdl will generate a WSDL.

Comment: Are you saying that you can't do RPC with SOAP?  I know that might not encompass the entire standard, but it was certainly the original motivation.  As far as whether or not the WSDL URL is part of the standard, I'll admit that you have me there.  It's usually the way I see it done, but I can't cite anything in the standard that mandates it.

Comment: You may have been confusing the fact that SOAP was derived from XML-RPC with the idea that SOAP was originally intended as an RPC. Yet note that WSDL, from the start, was able to describe document-style services, in addition to RPC style services. If RPC were the original motivation behind SOAP and WSDL, then one would expect that document-style services would have been absent from the original standard.

Answer (score 8):

Wikipedia says "The Web Services Description Language is an XML-based language that provides a model for describing Web services". Put another way, WSDL is to a web service, as javadoc is to a java library.

The really sweet thing about WSDL, though, is that software can generate a client and server using WSDL.

Answer (score 6):

REST is light-weight in terms of encoding, much more useful for light weight devices i.e. non strict APIs.

REST is format independent. XML, HTML, JSON all options are available.

REST provides abilities for on 2 point message transfer (not surprising since REST stands for REpresentational State Transfer) where WSDL/SOAP interaction is multiple point message interaction.

REST does not require a new extension for XML messages, where in WSDL/SOAP this is the case.

WSDL/SOAP uses multiple transport protocols, REST relies on only HTTP. Therefore WSDL/SOAP can be used like a RESTful way, however simple requests can be overly complicated/heavy weighted.

A simple analogy: REST is like a motoboy delivers your food easy and quick. XML extended WSDL/SOAP more like UPS delivery, more structured and serious stuff but comes with a cost.

Answer (score 5):

Some clear explanations (for SOAP and WSDL) can be found here as well.

[Difference between a SOAP message and a WSDL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541066/difference-between-a-soap-message-and-a-wsdl)

Answer (score 1):

A WSDL document describes a webservice. It specifies the location of the service and the methods of the service using these major elements:
 data types using in webservice
 data elements for each operation
 describe the operations that can be performed and the messages envolved

SOAP (Simple Object Access Protocol) is a messaging protocol that allows programs that run on disparate operating systems to communicate using http and xml.