# SOA - WSDL, how is it connected to other kinds of code?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl, soa

I have an assignment for school that's do to for tomorrow, I'm suppose to make a diagram about how i define Service Oriented Architecture.

The problem i have at the moment is that i have NO idea where the connection between for example pl/sql code and wsdl files are. I can't seem to find anything that explains that, but i just think I'm googling the wrong things, simply because i don't understand the connection.

so a wsdl file takes in parameters that's predefined to what the service needs and all that. but I've looked up wsdl code and i see no connection between the wsdl file and the application/service that needs these parameters to do something?

And what part does a ESB/OSB play in all this? 
the basics of SOA was easy to understand but the actual technology was not as easy... I'm sorry if you think I'm answering a stupid question but i really can't find anything on this topic by my self.. i think this entire SOA subject has gotten me a little confused...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are WSDL, SOAP and REST?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764681/what-are-wsdl-soap-and-rest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I got your questions right.

There are various tools in the industry (for Java there are: CXF, Axis2, JDK7/JAX-WS, etc.) that supports generation of code such that you can implement the service logic. The generated code include data types and a service skeleton class. The service skeleton is where you add your logic in. The tool I mentioned have 'hello world' example for WSDL 1st (aka, importing a WSDL file to generate the artifacts that are used to implement the service).

[Beware that implementing WSDLs does not make it SOA!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickmalik/archive/2007/01/16/your-soa-is-jabows-just-a-bunch-of-web-services-and-i-can-prove-it.aspx)

ESB, Enterprise Service Bus, is one technology out of several that supports enable SOA (there are also: Business Process Management, Service Registry, Service Repository, Business Activity Monitoring and so on).

Most ESBs provide these capabilities:

- Protocol Binding - e.g., HTTP, FTP, REST, SOAP, JSON, DCOM, CORBA, SAP RFC etc.
- [Message Exchange Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messaging_pattern) - e.g., synchronous vs. asynchronous
- Adapters
- Publish/Subscribe - e.g., by using JMS under the hoods
- Message Transformation
- Message Validation
- Message Routing
- Mediation Flows
- Security
- Service Policies
- Service Level Agreements
- Service Monitoring
- WS Standards Supported - e.g., ws-policy

OSB is Oracle's ESB.

Comment: then i don't think i understand this at all. All they talk about in SOA is making  everything flexible and making it able to communicate with other languages or operating systems, and also using services, but I'm guessing these are not the same thing at all which i have earlier though..? i watched this " http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hyXOuvyq2Q " by making pl/sql code in to a web service it could be used in more ways... but as i've understod it now, web services can't be pl/sql, java, c# files that was put on the web, its just xml/wsdl files.. which i cant see ANY funcion in at all..